# Selenium python not running on shell script ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to deploy a selenium script on ubuntu 20.04.3 however it is returning error mesage like so:

[error on jenkins like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bhKq.png)

My current script is like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
 
driver.get("https://python.org")
print(driver.title)
driver.close()
```

It is able to run locally however not on the ubuntu server
Someone please help me.

Comment: are you running the script under root user?

Comment: yes. it's under root user

Answer (score 0):

You have to download **the same version** of Chrome and chromedriver otherwise it won't work.

Here you can download the latest version of:

•**chromedriver**: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/

•**google chrome**: https://www.google.com/chrome/

Comment: how do I freeze the version of chromedriver and google crhome so that I do not have to always update the version?